# ObservableCollection Enumerator with filter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, collections

I need to filter out some items from an observable collection. Previously, with IEnumerable, I was doing:

```
private IEnumerable _myCollection {get; set;}
public IEnumerator<MyType> GetEnumerator()
{
   var filteredType = _myColletion.Where(t => t.MyProperty.State != States.NeedsDelete);
return filteredType.GetEnumerator();
}

System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
   return GetEnumerator();
}
```

I'm now using an `ObservableCollection`. How would I implement the same thing?

Edit (Context):

I'm keeping track of some entities, working with them in memory, and the idea is that, at the end, I push these entities back to the web service. Each object in the observable collection will have a state, such as "NeedsCreate", "NeedsDelete", "NeedsUpdate" or Unchanged. Then, I will go through each of these states and call the appropriate web service to synchronize these changes.

Comment: Some context information is needed, e.g., how/where this will be used. `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but looks like you know about this and want something else.

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question

Comment: @David The same applies for `ObservableCollection<T>`. Why not just return it's `GetEnumerator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well an [ObservalbeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) does inherit from a Collection and so on from an IEnumerable. The "exact same way" would be:

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<Type>();
public IEnumerator<Type> GetEnumerator() {
    return collection
        .Where(i => i.Property.State != States.NeedsDelete)
        .GetEnumerator();
}
```

Maybe I'm interpreting the wrong way. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Isn't GetEnumerator already implemented by ObservableCollection?

Comment: Of course it is, but your aim is to append a filter to the collection before you call the **GetEnumerator** method. The direct call would get you all of the entries